# Put data in #myModal popup Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popup

Its very simple but i don't see the solution.

How can I put a php var in this twitter bootstrap popup link?

`<a href="#myModal" title="Lees meer" value="12345" data-toggle="modal">Read More</a>`

And how can i get and print the value of this link in the popup field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If short tags are enabled:

```
<a 
    href="#myModal" 
    title="Lees meer" 
    value="12345" 
    data-toggle="modal" 
    data-phpvar="<?=$myVariable?>"
>
    Read More
</a>
```

else:

```
<a 
    href="#myModal" 
    title="Lees meer" 
    value="12345" 
    data-toggle="modal" 
    data-phpvar="<?php echo $myVariable; ?>"
>
    Read More
</a>
```

*both indented for readability - don't do this in actual HTML, it looks messy.*

And to get it in jQuery - *`.data("variable")` automatically gets attributes that start with `data-`*:

```
$("a[href=#myModal]").click(function() {
    alert($(this).data("phpvar"));
});
```

or use the `.attr` equivalent:

```
$("a[href=#myModal]").click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr("data-phpvar"));
});
```

and to output in the modal:

```
$("a[href=#myModal]").click(function() {
    var phpVariable = $(this).attr("data-phpvar");
    var modalObject = $($(this).attr("href"));
    modalObject.find(".modal-body").text(phpVariable); //You might also use .html()
});
```

[**JSFiddle demo of the code working**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZHbRG/)

Comment: if I do that get I a mesaage whit "undifened"

Comment: @RaymondvanOs Ah sorry- it doesn't have the ID "myModal", but the href. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks its works great! but how can I echo this whit php in the popup field?

Comment: @RaymondvanOs Do you want to have something from PHP show in the contents of the modal popup?

Comment: Yes i want echo te phpvar whit php in the modal popup

Answer (score 0):

*Thanks a lot **h2ooooooo***

I have the short tags enabled and I will build the link ass follow:

```
<a href="#myModal" 
   title="Bewerken" 
   role="button" 
   data-toggle="modal" 
   data-phpvar="<?php echo $value['i_id_pk'] . '||' . $value['c_user'] . '||'. $value['i_user_type_id_fk'];?>">
    <i class="icon-edit"></i>
</a>
```

I send the values of data-phpvar with JQuery to the #myModal Popup. I use a OnClick event to get the values out of the a href data-phpvar. Like this:

```
<script>
    $("a[href=#myModal]").click(function() {
        var str = $(this).attr("data-phpvar");
        var substr = str.split('||');

        $("[name=user_id]").val(substr[0]);
        $("[name=c_chance_user_name]").val(substr[1]);
        $("[name=validation_c_user]").val(substr[1]);
        $("[name=c_chance_user_type]").val(substr[2]);

        $("span.userName").text(substr[1]);
    });
</script>
```

It will work but, can I do this piece of JQuery make shorter or in a better way?

Eventually I put the values ​​out of the a href data-phpvar in the textfields inside the popup. The textfield must have the same name like the JQuery names:

> $("[name=user_id]").val(substr[0]); 
>   or
>   $("[name=c_chance_user_name]").val(substr[1](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals));

The html textfield in the popup is like this:

```
    <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel">Wijzig gebruiker "<span class="userName"></span>"</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
             <input class="span3" id="appendedPrependedInput" type="text" name="c_chance_user_name" value="" minlength="3" required />
             <input class="span3" type="text" data-validation-match-match="c_chance_user_name" name="validation_c_user" minlength="3" required />
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
             <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Sluiten</button>
             <button class="btn btn-success" name="chanceBtn"><li class="icon-ok-circle icon-white"></li> Opslaan</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

> You can find this popup plug-in on [www.twitter.github.com/](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals)

Comment: You don't **have** to use `data-phpvar`. It can be `data-anything`, so you could make 4 attributes. `data-uid`, `data-username`, `data-validation`, `data-user-type` etc.